# Rails4: Using Rails Concerns in calling callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, callback, activesupport-concern

Using rails4, I am trying to implement notification model. Here I use ActiveSupport::Concern to separate my notification related code from the model.
    create_notification_module.rb

```
module CreateNotificationModule
   extend ActiveSupport::Concern
   include ActiveModel::Dirty

   included do
     after_update :notify 
     after_create :notify
     after_create :notify
   end
   def notify
     record = Notification.new( 
                  :ref_table => self.class,                           
                  :ref_id => self.id,                          
                  :receiver => ? ,  # owner of the parent model if parent exists
                  :sender => current_user.id,     
                  :details => self.changes,                   
                  :is_read => 0)
     record.save!

   end
```

Here I need to know from which controller/model this callback is called, so that I can write my switch case. For ex., 
case comment: to get the owner of the message to which user comments
case like: to get the owner of msg/cmt which is liked etc.,  any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what your needs are but I would recommend you rethink how his is going to work because it seems like you are misusing the idea of a concern and are going to get yourself into a code mess down the line. If you are writing a switch statement and checking types to implement custom behaviour for each class I think that a concern is the wrong tool to use. A concern shared among several classes adds the same behaviour to all of the those classes. Seems like you want to share some code to DRY things out but then want to customize some aspects based on which class sends the message. Perhaps a helper method that builds a Notification or a NotificationBuilder class would be better here. Then each class can get a Notification and set it's attributes according to their needs. That way future programmers won't be surprised when the behaviour of Comment and User are different even though they both include CreateNotificationModule (which implies that the behaviour is the same).

I can highly recommend the book [Practical Object Oriented Design in Ruby: An Agile Primer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0096BYG7C); it explains much more eloquently and convincingly than I can why the switch statement you are going to write is a bad idea.

I realize this isn't actually an answer, but it didn't fit in the comments. Sorry for that.

Comment: more widely, why a callback and/or a validation do not works in concern ?